# Connection being attempted between VS 2013 Test Controller and TFS Build Agent, failing

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, mstest

I'm getting the following error when I start load tests using VS 2013, when the load tests are kicked as part of a TFS build (an `MSTEST` call).

```
Failed calling event listener
 Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Execution.RemoteObjectContainer`1[Microsoft.Visua
 lStudio.TestTools.Controller.IControllerEvents]: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): 
 No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

The architecture is completely `VS 2013 Update 4`, but for some reason the test controller is trying to reach out to my build controller on a strange port (in this case port 58687.

I've checked my TFS Build Controller configuration, and the only configurable port I can find is 8080, and connections succeed from that. Why is port 58687 being used, and is there an additional rule I need to add to the firewall for some range of dynamic ports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet this is a blocked port somewhere.  Try running Wireshark to find the blocked port.